# Angular use selector with createElement

Tags: angular

Good I do not know if this is from google translator, I want to add a component to the html using createElement but it does not show me anything

"app-GridWidget that component is a newly created angular component"

```js
test (): void{
    const compt = document.createElement( "app-GridWidget" );
    document.getElementById( "test" ).appendChild( compt );

  }
```

```html
<button (click)="test()">Test</button>

<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You Created element instead of createComponent. You should go through below link. It may help you.
Ref: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: let's imagine this is the component:
Name:GridWidget.component.ts
Code:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component( {
  selector: 'app-gridwidget',
  template: `
  <p>
    GridWidget works!
  </p>
`
} )
export class GridWidgetComponent implements OnInit {

Comment: are you mean add component dynamically?

Comment: wrong understood from mine.
Ref: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader 
I edited the answer.

Comment: That works when the tag already exists in the HTML, but the idea is to add the tag later because it is not known how many tags are going to be created.

Comment: Are you using dynamic component with viewContainerRef?

Comment: I hope so, this is what I found "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-component-loader-nppdjc", the tag is written in the html but not shown(I'll try refreshing the page to see)

Comment: what you mean tag here and what has not shown while you refreshing the page?

Comment: It is difficult to explain, I need to show but it is basically that when the component is already rendered by angular and I add tags (they are known as "selector") of other components in the html it does not show me those components, I have to look for another strategy .. .